# Load an image in to one cell UITableView - xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have 2 arrays of information that I'm loading in to an UITableView control through the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 0)

        cell.textLabel.text = [arryTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    else
        cell.textLabel.text = [arryTableActions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;
}
```

I want the top array (arryTableData) which is below this to have as the first cell an image of the location.

```
arryTableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", locName],
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", locPhone],
                            @"Address Info",
                            @"Access Icons",
                            nil];
```

So just before locName I'd like locImage to be in there. How do I load an image in to the array and then display it in the cell?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend NOT to load a UIImage into a NSArray.
Just add the "ImageName" (filename) into the NSArray as NSString.

When you need to show your image, do this:

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arryTableImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

You need to load NSString into the NSArray arryTableImage.

Okay four you?

Comment: +1 When possible, I prefer to store image locations as well to avoid the memory hit until I need the image.  Note:  Using UIImage's `imageNamed:` method will cache the image.  That's great depending on the situation.  If you have a large image you only want to use once, use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead to avoid caching.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. How do I set it to only appear on the first row and just show the image, nothing else (basically it's the logo for the location and I want to show it quite big)